# Resource Not Found: xacro

Tags: xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I'm new to ROS and currently using indigo on 14.04 LTS.
I have a package called `myrobot_description`,with `launch` and `urdf` folder in it.
i am trying to launch a `.launch` file to display a urdf model in rviz,but facing this problem after i cd into the `launch` folder and run `roslaunch display.launch`

```
edmond@edmond:~/rosws/src/myrobot_description/launch$ roslaunch display.launch
... logging to /home/edmond/.ros/log/97f94786-aa1e-11e5-9e12-c81f662b396f/roslaunch-edmond-32318.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 307, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 217, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 132, in _load_config
    roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 451, in load_config_default
    loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 730, in load
    self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 702, in _load_launch
    self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 646, in _recurse_load
    self._param_tag(tag, context, ros_config, verbose=verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 256, in _param_tag
    vals = self.opt_attrs(tag, context, ('value', 'textfile', 'binfile', 'command'))
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 202, in opt_attrs
    return [self.resolve_args(tag_value(tag,a), context) for a in attrs]
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 183, in resolve_args
    return substitution_args.resolve_args(args, context=context.resolve_dict, resolve_anon=self.resolve_anon)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 312, in resolve_args
    resolved = _resolve_args(resolved, context, resolve_anon, commands)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 325, in _resolve_args
    resolved = commands[command](resolved, a, args, context)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 141, in _find
    source_path_to_packages=source_path_to_packages)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 184, in _find_executable
    full_path = _get_executable_path(rp.get_path(args[0]), path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 200, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)

ResourceNotFound: xacro
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/edmond/rosws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

so basically i suppose the problem here is `ResourceNotFound: xacro`, can any one help me on this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!

---

Edit: as gvdhoom mentioned, the `xacro` package is missing.i tried installing `ros-indigo-xacro`, and the problem is half solved.It showed that a `urdf_tutorial` package is missing and i tried installing `ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial`, it worked.
Thanks for your instant help.

(btw,it is kind of weird because I've chosen ros full desktop installation, so it should not be any necessary package missing, isn't it?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223053/resource-not-found:-xacro/) by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-12-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two things:

- do you have the `xacro` package installed?
- have you sourced the appropriate `setup.bash` file?

Also:

> i cd into the `launch` folder and run `roslaunch display.launch`

while this works (`roslaunch` can work with (absolute) paths), it's typically better to use the `<PKG> <FILE>` variant, as that will work from any directory (provided `PKG` is on the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`). In your case it would become:

```
roslaunch myrobot_description display.launch
```

---

Edit:

> btw,it is kind of weird because I've chosen ros full desktop installation, so it should not be any necessary package missing, isn't it?

Yes, that is strange. `xacro` is supposed to be part of the [robot meta-package](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0142.html#robot-metapackage), which in turn is part of the [desktop](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0142.html#desktop-variants) variant. Installing `ros-indigo-desktop` should have installed `xacro` as well. Can you provide some more information on how you installed ROS? Which tutorial (if any) did you follow?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2